# summarise ids with the same row values data frame r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, filtering

In my `DATA` below, I wonder how to list the unique `ID`s whose ALL `Type` rows ONLY consist of `A` to achieve my `Desired_output`?

I tried the following without success:

```
library(tidyverse)
group_by(DATA, ID) %>%
     filter(
        all("A" %in% Type))
```

```
DATA <- read.table(h=T,text=
"
ID      Type
1        A
1        A
1        A
2        B
2        B
2        A
3        A
3        A")

Desired_output =
"
ID       Type
1        A
1        A
1        A
3        A
3        A
"
```

Comment: `DATA %>% filter(all(Type %in% "A"), .by = ID)` or in your original code, switch `... %>% all("A" %in% Type)` with `... %>% all(Type %in% "A")`

Comment: `%in%` is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), so the order of the operands matters. The return value of it will be the length of the _first_ argument, so `"A" %in% Type` will always return length-1, but what you need is to return the same length as the number of rows in the current group. For that, you need `Type %in% "A"`. There is definitely a clear use-case for `"A" %in% Type`, but if you're looking to filter to just that type, then `filter(Type == "A")` seems much more direct (and it does not need to be grouped)

Comment: FYI, your `read.table` is broken? I get `argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments` since you're using uber-short argument names, fixed with `header=TRUE, text="..."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `==` here, not `%in%`

```
group_by(DATA, ID) %>%
  filter(
    all(Type == "A"))
#      ID Type 
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 A    
# 2     1 A    
# 3     1 A    
# 4     3 A    
# 5     3 A
```

Comment: `%in%` works too, the issue was the OP just had `all("A" %in% Type)` in the `filter` statement, which would return `TRUE` for any `ID` with at least one "A"

Comment: But why bother with `%in%` if you are just looking for a single value? It just seems to complicate matters.

Comment: Oh I'm not saying you shouldn't use `==`, just that the use of `%in%` vs `==` is not necessarily the core of the problem in this specific question so clarifying why the OP was experiencing this issue